# nodejs msnodesql error install on Vista32

Tags: node.js

When try to install msnodesql package on Vista 32, I get the error:
C:\Users\Administrator>npm install msnodesql@latest

npm http GET htps://registry.npmjs.org/msnodesql

npm http 304 htps://registry.npmjs.org/msnodesql

> msnodesql@0.2.1 install C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\msnodesql
>   node scripts/install.js

You are downloading Microsoft Driver for Node.js for SQL Server from
Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at
http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/2/6E2D7972-E54D-45AA-8AB6-41E616035147/EULA.rtf and in the project folder to which the
software is downloaded. Check the package for additional dependencies, which
may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If
you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant
components from your device.


**install.js: Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-ia32.msi**

npm ERR! msnodesql@0.2.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the msnodesql@0.2.1 install script.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the msnodesql package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js

npm ERR! You can get their info via:

npm ERR!     npm owner ls msnodesql

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6002

npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nod
ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "msnodesql@latest"

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Administrator

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23

npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\npm-debug.log

The node-gyp package is install OK.
I have installel VS 2005, VS 2008 Express VS 2010 Express.
SQL 2005.

I cover all requests for SO and SQL that are on Microsoft download page.

First I see package msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-ia32.msi (????) can't find this package on NET.

Sugestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the approved answer by **kernel**
to this similar question "Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-x64.msi"

here:
[Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-x64.msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661811/unable-to-download-msnodesql-0-2-1-v0-10-x64-msi)