# is there a way of using node.js mssql package with a Trusted_Connection user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2008, node-mssql

I have been trying to connected to sql server 2008 for the past few days using trusted user connection. I have had complete success with the username/password connection string. However, when I try to connect as a trusted user, I completely fail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there appear to be a couple drivers, which one exactly as you are using. Also are you running on Windows ?

Comment: I am running Windows. I have tried using tedious but there doesn't appear to be a trusted connection option and I can't get msnodesql installed.

Comment: well in this (https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql, there appears to be use Microsoft Driver for Node.js for SQL Server, which appears to have a trusted option).  Not sure if will work or not(don't have easy way to test it)

Comment: This is actually the one i am using. You need to have msnodesql installed to invoke the trusted connection option and that package doesn't seem to install.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661811/unable-to-download-msnodesql-0-2-1-v0-10-x64-msi  This might help?  Seems to be some issues with getting it downloaded /etc...