# Deploy Node.js on Azure Website error (msnodesql driver)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, node-mssql

I want to deploy my node.js on azure website

but it always error

it shows that error about install "msnodesql"

but I only use "mssql" with default driver "tedious"

how to solve this problem?

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'npm-debug.log'
Copying file: 'node_modules\msnodesql\scripts\install.js'
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.10.32.
npm WARN package.json RCBulletinAPI@0.0.1 No repository field.
> msnodesql@0.2.1 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\msnodesql
> node scripts/install.js
You are downloading Microsoft Driver for Node.js for SQL Server from
Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at
http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/2/6E2D7972-E54D-45AA-
8AB6-41E616035147/EULA.rtf and in the project folder to which the
software is downloaded. Check the package for additional dependencies, which
may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If
you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant
components from your device.
install.js: Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-ia32.msi
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.32\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
npm ERR! msnodesql@0.2.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the msnodesql@0.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the msnodesql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls msnodesql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.32\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
```

Comment: Please refer to this link for details on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661811/unable-to-download-msnodesql-0-2-1-v0-10-x64-msi

Comment: But I want to deploy it on Azure, It doesn't show error at local environment, only when I deploy it

Comment: Try to change the node.exe version of your azure website to 0.8.x

Comment: which version of node are you using locally ?

Comment: I'm using v0.10.35 is there any problem with this version?